# Displaying Custom Category loop in homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Thing is, In the homepage of my theme, I want to show post from different category in Different Div. Each DIV will contain 3 post from a category. I need a loop that can pick last 3 post from a specific Category. Can't find any suitable ans for it.

To explain things more easily, here is a demo picture of the Content section,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK5Bl.png

It will be a great help, if someone help me with the code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=10&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This should get you started. You need to use this code twice. Where it says `cat=10`, you should enter your category ID (you can check this when you click on a Category from the admin panel, the the browser it will show something like this http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=4&post_type=post)

Where it says `tag_ID` is the ID of your category.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a different method on a page of the site I'm building which allows me to run multiple loops in one page and specify the category for each one. This method I personally like better as it is more straightforward to me, and I can define the category with the slug instead of the ID.

Instead of using `have_posts()` and such, you use `WP_Query()` after defining your array and then `wp_reset_postdata()` to end your loop. The benefit is that you can keep running loops this way.

I'm also loading the data from custom fields in my posts using `get_post_meta`, but this method will work without that stuff.

```
<div class="audioGrid">

    <?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post',                        
                   'category_name' => 'audio',                    
                   'posts_per_page' => 3,
                   'order' => 'DESC' );

    $query1 = new WP_Query($args);        

    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
        $query1->the_post();

    ?>                              
        <div id="<?php echo( basename(get_permalink()) ); ?>" class="grid_item">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'audio-thumb' ); ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_description', true); ?></p>
            <a target="blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_link', true); ?>"></a>
        </div>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php } ?>

</div>  <?php // end Audio Grid ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div class="videoGrid">

    <?php 
    $args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'post',                        
                   'category_name' => 'video',                    
                   'posts_per_page' => 3,
                   'order' => 'DESC' );

    $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);        

    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();

    ?>                              
        <div id="<?php echo( basename(get_permalink()) ); ?>" class="grid_item">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'video-thumb' ); ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_description', true); ?></p>
            <a target="blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_link', true); ?>"></a>
        </div>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php } ?>

</div>  <?php // end Video Grid ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Another cool thing I'm doing is using a custom field to define the order of things and using `meta_key` and `meta_value_num` to get that number and force the order how I want, and since this site isn't complicated, defining the order this way is convenient. I just use leading zeroes to make it easy: 001, 002, 003, etc

```
<?php 
    $args2 = array( 'post_type' => 'post',                        
                    'category_name' => 'video',                    
                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                    'meta_key' => 'video_order',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                    'order' => 'ASC' );

    $query2 = new WP_Query($args2);        

    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();

?>
```

Anyway, hope this helps if you need to use multiple loops to pull posts from different categories.